# Help in SOQL Query

Tags: apex, soql

Trying to create query for Contacts Table and Team Member Table. Would like to get data from contacts of off the Opportunity record like Opportunity ID, Contact Name, Phone.

Also would like to get data of off the Opportunity record Opportunity ID, Team Member where Member Role = "Assosiate".

Comment: what did you try and why did that fail?

Answer (score 3):

You can query the `OpportunityContactRole` and use relationships to get Fields from both the Contact and the Opportunity.

```
[SELECT Contact.Field, Opportunity.Field FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE Role = 'Associate' AND OpportunityId = :yourOppId]
```